# How to set value to Form in Angular using FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-forms

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="gGroup">
  <label for="grouplabel">Group</label>
  <select formControlName="groupControl" [(ngModel)]="groupobj" (ngModelChange)="onSelectGroup($event)" id="group" class="form-control">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [selected]="current_group === group.name">{{group.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How can I set the value of the `<select>` field to **Select** dynamically in the Component?

I looked at the docs, https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel but still no example that can help me.

Attempt:

`this.gGroup.get('groupControl').setValue('Select');`

Comment: Try changing the value of `this.groupobj`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a good idea to mix Reactive Forms and Template Driven Forms together, that is formGroup/formControlName and ngModel binding in the same form control.

If I am not mistaken, this is deprecated in Angular 6, and will be removed in Angular 7. At least that was the warning I got in console few days ago. Simply put, use Reactive Forms if you need to work with dynamic form rendering and complex form validation (cross field validation, custom validators etc.), and use Template Driven Forms for simpler forms that require simple validation.

Now back to your question. In Reactive Forms (in your specific example), a value can be set in the following way:

```
this.gGroup.controls[this.groupControl].setValue()
```

Please check the following link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kskgbp

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to check Angular 6 depricates to use ngModel  in reactive forms

Comment: I am not quite sure. It has to be mentioned somewhere on the release notes. As far as I remember, whenever I used both types of forms, i got `console warning` that it will be deprecated in next release (that was Angular 7)

Comment: kindly use something like this when you are not aware of control is actually attached to the FormGroup ```this.gGroup.contains('controlName') && this.gGroup.get('controlName').setValue('sample data');```

Comment: the get('controlName') is working perfectly well.  Mohan Ram is right

Answer (score 10):

I figured out a way to do this:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <select name="option" ngModel>
    <option value="" disabled>Choose an option</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option">
      {{ option.title }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

```
this.f.controls.state.setValue(this.options[0]);
```

Check this example I made:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpeth8

Answer (score 4):

If we want to set value to all the `formControl` inside a `formGroup` then you can go with `setValue` or if we want to set value to any one of the `formControl` inside a `formGroup` then we can go with `patchValue`

**setValue**(assuming formGroup has 2 formControls)

```
formgroup.setValue({name: ‘Mocrosoft’, age: ‘25’});
```

**patchValue**

```
formgroup.patchValue({name:’Mocrosoft’});
```

Or you can do,

```
this.yourFormgroup.get("yourFormControl").setValue("yourValue");
```

Comment: While using `formgroup.setValue({name: ‘Mocrosoft’, age: ‘25’});` we've to make sure all the values are supplied else, the remaining form controls will throw `Must supply a value for form control with name: otherFormcontrolNames` error. This way cant be used to update single control's value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following examples that i have been created.
HTML:

```
  <form [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <label for="grouplabel">Animals</label>
        <select formControlName="animalName" class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let animal of animals">{{animal.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Typescript:

```
  myform: FormGroup;
  animals: String[] = ["cat", "cow", "elephant"];
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
   this.myform = this.formBuilder.group({
      animalName : [""]
    })`enter code here`
  }
```

live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1bmzur