# To set default selected item in Select with multiple selection component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using **Select with multiple selection** component.

[image]

I want to make 2 items to be selected by default like this.

[image]

I have surfed,but i got resources only for **Basic select** component, How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you edit in this stackblitz link?  https://stackblitz.com/angular/xamkeymbbvvk?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done it here please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zs2wa5?file=app/select-multiple-example.ts

```
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings;
  toppingList: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.toppings = new FormControl();
    this.toppingList= ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
    this.toppings.value = ['Mushroom', 'Onion', ];
    console.log(this.toppings);
  }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine,Thank you..:)

Comment: welcome, please mark this answer correct, Maybe it will help someone else having the same question.

Comment: I had to use `setValue`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992178/how-to-set-value-to-form-in-angular-using-formcontrol