# Unable to make default selection in selection with multiple component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am having 2 form fields `Vehicle type` i,e **(Autocomplete with filter component)** and `Vehicle model` i,e **(Select with multiple selection  component)** are displayed as shown in below image:

[image]

**Scenario:** Here on selecting  `Vehicle type`(for ex bikes) the associated `Vehicle Model` (i,e bikes model) are displayed as shown in below image:

[image]

Now i want some of the `vehicle Models` to be selected by default like this:

[image]

## I Know this is the duplicate of this   [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736875/to-set-default-selected-item-in-select-with-multiple-selection-component?noredirect=1#comment92399330_52736875)

But here my scenario is different, In that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736875/to-set-default-selected-item-in-select-with-multiple-selection-component?noredirect=1#comment92399330_52736875) they have **set select component items to by default** using the `constructor`.But in my case i am already having the `constructor` for another imported `component`(i,e Chips autocomplete) component.Due lack of typescript knowledge,I am unable to it. I am stuck here.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lyujqm-ruakqs?file=app/select-multiple-example.ts) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [(ngModel)]="sel" in:

```
 <mat-select placeholder="Vehicle Model"  multiple [(ngModel)]="sel">
```

and in TS set which ones should be selected:

this.offeringControl.valueChanges.subscribe((d) => {

```
    if (d === 'Cars') {
      this.vehicles = this.carsmodel;
      this.sel=['Car1', 'Car2'];
    } else if (d === 'Bikes') {
      this.vehicles = this.bikesmodel;
       this.sel=['Bike1', 'Bike2'];
    } else {
      this.vehicles = this.cyclesmodel;
       this.sel=['Cycle1', 'Cycle1'];
    }
  });
```

Comment: You are right, but i am having many  `vehicle types`. One more is called `cars`, If i select `cars` in the  **vehicle type**, the by default selected `cars model` as to come in the `vehicle model` list, i want it many `vehicles types` not for a single vehicle.

Comment: If possible see the full **stackblitz** example.

Comment: @Empty_Soul ok! I updated it! In when you change the vehicles.. you can set which ones are selected.

Comment: Thank for your answer.